# How do I autofit a column that has merged cells?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

In C#, for an excel spreadsheet, how do I autofit a column that has merged cells?  I tried doing this with the code below, but it does not autofit the column.

Here is my code so far:

```
Worksheet xlSheet  

xlSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Autobiographies and Titles, Autobiographies and Titles, Autobiographies  
and Titles, Autobiographies and Titles, Autobiographies and Titles, Autobiographies and Titles,  
Autobiographies and Titles, Autobiographies and Titles";  

Range hRangeSubsystemName = xlSheet.get_Range("A2", "G2");  
hRangeSubsystemName.MergeCells = true;  
hRangeSubsystemName.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

Comment: Please avoid including tags in your question title.

Comment: After the cells are merged does Excel still see them as separate columns? If it doesn't then your code doesn't make sense. What may be more appropriate would be `xlSheet.get_Range("A2").AutoFit()` or similar. Note that I'm no expert in Excel interop though so it's just a guess based on my interpretation of what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use autofit on columns with merged cells in Excel.

See MS support article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/212010

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to do this with Gembox which you might find helpful

```
private int AutoSizeMergedCells(CellRange myMergedCells, string text)
    {
        var file = new ExcelFile();
        file.Worksheets.Add("AutoSize");
        var ws = file.Worksheets[0];

        ws.Cells[0, 0].Column.Width = myMergedCells.Sum(x => x.Column.Width);
        ws.Cells[0, 0].Value = text;
        ws.Cells[0, 0].Style.WrapText = true;
        ws.Cells[0, 0].Row.AutoFit();
        var result = ws.Cells[0, 0].Row.Height;
        file = null;
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can convert this into C#, but I found a VB macro [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/76182-autofit-row-height-display-wrapped-text.html) that will simulate the autofit of any merged cells on the active sheet. Source credits parry from MrExcel.com

```vb
Sub AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight()
Dim CurrentRowHeight As Single, MergedCellRgWidth As Single
Dim CurrCell As Range
Dim ActiveCellWidth As Single, PossNewRowHeight As Single
Dim StartCell As Range, c As Range, MergeRng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim a() As String, isect As Range, i


'Take a note of current active cell
Set StartCell = ActiveCell

'Create an array of merged cell addresses that have wrapped text
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If c.MergeCells Then
    With c.MergeArea
    If .Rows.Count = 1 And .WrapText = True Then
        If MergeRng Is Nothing Then
            Set MergeRng = c.MergeArea
            ReDim a(0)
            a(0) = c.MergeArea.Address
        Else
        Set isect = Intersect(c, MergeRng)
            If isect Is Nothing Then
                Set MergeRng = Union(MergeRng, c.MergeArea)
                ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
                a(UBound(a)) = c.MergeArea.Address
            End If
        End If
    End If
    End With
End If
Next c


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop thru merged cells
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
Range(a(i)).Select
      With ActiveCell.MergeArea
            If .Rows.Count = 1 And .WrapText = True Then
                'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                CurrentRowHeight = .RowHeight
                ActiveCellWidth = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
                For Each CurrCell In Selection
                    MergedCellRgWidth = CurrCell.ColumnWidth + MergedCellRgWidth
                Next
                .MergeCells = False
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergedCellRgWidth
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
                PossNewRowHeight = .RowHeight
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = ActiveCellWidth
                .MergeCells = True
                .RowHeight = IIf(CurrentRowHeight > PossNewRowHeight, _
                  CurrentRowHeight, PossNewRowHeight)
            End If
        End With
MergedCellRgWidth = 0
Next i

StartCell.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Clean up
Set CurrCell = Nothing
Set StartCell = Nothing
Set c = Nothing
Set MergeRng = Nothing
Set Cell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
     private double AutoSizeMergedCells( string text)        
    { 
        Excel.Worksheet ws = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];
         `enter code here`ws.Cells[14, 10].ColumnWidth = 9.29+7.43+10.71+11.29;(size width range)
         ws.Cells[14, 10].Value = text;
             ws.Cells[14, 10].Style.WrapText = true;
                    ws.Cells[14, 10].Rows.AutoFit();
                    var result = ws.Cells[14, 10].RowHeight;  
          ws.Cells[14, 10].Value = "";
                    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I've made workaround. After filling Worksheet with data, I use my ExtensionMethod `mySheet.AutoFitRowsWithMergedCells();`

I'm iterating all data in worksheet. When I find merged cell I copy it's sizes and value into not merged temporary cell before last used column in same row, executes AutoFit(), witch now works correctly and removes temp cell.

```
public static void AutoFitRowsWithMergedCells(this Worksheet worksheet)
{
    var range = worksheet.UsedRange;

    int rowsCount = range.Rows.Count;
    int columnsCount = range.Columns.Count;

    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= rowsCount; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnsCount; columnIndex++)
        {
            var subRange = range.GetSubRange(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            if ((bool)subRange.MergeCells && subRange.Value != null)
            {
                var mergedArea = subRange.MergeArea;
                double mergedColumnsWidth = 0;
                foreach (dynamic column in mergedArea.Columns)
                {
                    mergedColumnsWidth += column.ColumnWidth;
                }

                var tempRange = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnsCount + 1]; 
                tempRange.Value = subRange.Value;
                tempRange.Style.WrapText = true;
                double originalTempColumnWidth = tempRange.Columns[1].ColumnWidth; 
                tempRange.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = mergedColumnsWidth;
                subRange.EntireRow.AutoFit();
                double correctHeight = subRange.EntireRow.RowHeight;
                tempRange.Value = string.Empty;
                tempRange.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = originalTempColumnWidth;
                subRange.EntireRow.RowHeight = correctHeight;
            }
        }
    }
}
```